# What is the best alternative to OnValidate for automated changes in editor?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

If I want to make automated changes in editor, I generally use OnValidate. Over the years I've run into many issues with it so I'm looking for an alternative.

Example: There is a ladder object with a ladder script on it. When I change the Size variable on the ladder component, I want it to also change the size of the SpriteRenderer, which is set to Tiled mode. Unfortunately, OnValidate doesn't like you using SendMessage and you can get funky results.

I am **NOT** looking to solve this issue specifically. I already use an editor script to solve it. I am simply looking for a way to automate changes without using OnValidate so that I have more freedom.

I thought maybe an editor script could do this, but I'd really like to avoid having to do that for every single case individually. Maybe there is a way to do an editor script that could handle all scripts trying to do this? Maybe an editor script that works with interfaces?

EDIT: Changed the title and text of the post to be clearer.

Comment: Things are only saved, if they are serialized .. if you are setting anything not serialized (non-serializable types like e.g. `Dictionary`, properties (in contrary to fields) or `private` fields then it will be lost as soon as the instance is reloaded. Reloading of the scene is e.g. happening when entering or exiting playmode, might happen on script recompilation, everytime you close the Editor or open a different scene .. etc

Comment: Yes. But the thing that was not being saved was a list and it was public. And I'm not too concerned about that issue alone. I am trying to find a better alternative for any kinds of automated changes by script in editor than using OnValidate.

Comment: well of what type was the list? and in general `a better alternative for any kinds of automated changes` sounds quite broad ... do you have an actual use case example?

Comment: Yes, it is broad, but that's sort of the point. I want to find a method that can cover most cases where I need a script to automatically update a variable. OnValidate runs any time a change is made in inspector (and at other times). I need something like that, something that can be done on any script (or an editor script that can do this for every script) automatically. I have two use case examples and they are in my post. 1. A ladder whose height and length variables change the rect transform size (and other things) and a variable that needs to be auto-added to a list.

Comment: I don't need solutions to each of these issues individually. I already came up with solutions and have it working. I just know there must be a way to more easily handle all my cases with some editor script or method that checks variables and changes things in a way that saves properly and doesn't cause issues with SendMessage.

Comment: If I understand right, what you have is: Objects which have an appeareance that is depending on property values you are setting in the editor, and you want that the appeareance is updated accordingly even outside play mode. Right?
In that case, I've run into similar issues. It seems like Unity sadly does not support this usecase very well once the objects become more complex. My solution was not to use the editor itself for that and instead do designing in play mode. Then this asset helps making the changes persist: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/play-mode-saver-104836

Comment: That said, RectTransform is generally a bit unintuitive when used from code. The issue might not be that you use the OnValidate function.

Comment: @ThomasFinch `OnValidate runs any time a change is made in inspector. I need something like that`. yes, `OnValidate` does exactly that I still: I don't see the problem. With show me a use case example I mean a code where the issue occures so we can reproduce it. As said `OnValidate` should be enough for any case where you are changing **serialized** fields.

Comment: @AlexGeorg I do not want to save changes from play mode. I want various variables on an object to automatically change based on other variables or based on my needs at the time. (I solved it though)

Comment: @derHugo Again, I don't need you to solve the individual issues with OnValidate. I'm already 100% sure the issue is something inherent about OnValidate. It does not allow SendMessage and it has some other problems. I just wanted an alternative to OnValidate. Fortunately I figured out a solution and have posted it as an answer for future people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with a solution. I created a base class that all other classes in my game will inherit from. It looks like this:

```
public class BaseClass : MonoBehaviour {
    [HideInInspector] public bool NeedsAutoUpdate;
    protected void OnValidate() { NeedsAutoUpdate = !Application.isPlaying; }
    public virtual void AutoUpdate() { NeedsAutoUpdate = false; }
}
```

So it's set up to track when OnValidate has happened only if it's not in play mode. If you want it to run in play mode too, just replace "!Application.isPlaying" with "true". Then there's a virtual AutoUpdate() which sets it back to false. Then I made an editor script.

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(BaseClass),true), CanEditMultipleObjects]
public class BaseClassEditor : Editor {

    public override void OnInspectorGUI() {
        
        base.OnInspectorGUI();

        var Objs = serializedObject.targetObjects;
        foreach (var Obj in Objs) {

            var Base = Obj as BaseClass;
            if (Base == null) continue;

            EditorApplication.delayCall += () => {
                if (Base.NeedsAutoUpdate) { Base.AutoUpdate(); }
            };
            
        }

    }
    
}
```

This will check if anything that inherits from the base class needs an auto update, and then run it. Using delay call ensures inspectors are fully updated before it does this to avoid the issues that OnValidate has. Note that if you have a class inherit from BaseClass, but that class already has it's own CustomEditor then you'll need to have that custom editor inherit from BaseClassEditor instead of Editor to make it work.

Lastly, on any class I want to AutoUpdate, I make sure it is inheriting from BaseClass (at least somewhere down the line) and add an override of AutoUpdate.

```
public override void AutoUpdate() {
    base.AutoUpdate();
    // Make changes here
}
```